# How to fix the URL triangle lock for Magento website?

Tags: magento, url, ssl, ssl-certificate

How can I fix this issue. I am using Magento.
[Click here to the Website Link](https://www.trenpon.com/index.php/customer/account/login/)

Comment: Normally the triangle lock should be in green, what is the issue I am facing?

Answer (score 0):

All your resource and image path must be replace with https I have found on your site like link http://www.trenpon.com/   all link and images and file path link change to https.

Comment: I am a noob, can you tell me how do I change it to https?

Comment: go to your code files and search whithin it where you found http:// replace with https://

Comment: Okay I thing I fixed can you take a look at it by clicking "Log In", if you click the lock you well see only one is secured and the other one still have the triangle. I don't know how to fix that one

Comment: in each page log in page checkout page, cart page ,category page , product page , about us page all page you need to check code and replace static link http with https then your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

The code in your home page has 93 instances where you have hard-coded http:// in the URL. There are 41 instances with the https:// prefix. While not all cause the mixed content warning, there are several that are resources served over http. You can go to the console in most modern browsers and see the resources that are causing the warning.

Here are some options:

1. Use relative URLs for your internal resources.
2. Use URLs without a scheme (http: or https:).
3. Code everything to use HTTPs.